# Linking To An Embedded VC in A Container Of A VC Embedded In A UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ibaction

I have the following storyboard structure:

[image]

Essentially I have a UIButon that I want to link to the "TargetTableViewController" via an `IBAction` - **NOT** by 'Ctrl+Dragging' but programatically by way of some code instead.

I believe I have to present "NavViewControllerTwo" as a NavigationController (as it 'holds' "HoldingViewController") and have tried various renditions of this via the many threads at StackOverflow. But this did not work.

I suspect it is because the actual "TargetTableViewController" is embedded in a `ContainerView` of "HoldingViewController" and that causes the problems.

I have tried implementing other renditions of presenting "TargetTableViewController" as a `child` of the "HoldingViewController", but that caused me more problems.

I realise I may have over-complicated things here, but the reason for the container is I want to display a BannerView at the bottom of my eventually presented view.

If anyone can be kind to point me in the right direction, I will be very grateful. Thank you for your time.

** CLARIFICATION **

I am actually trying to present "HoldingViewController" as that would effectively display my "TargetTableViewController".

Please refer to amended image below:

[image]

Apologies for the confusion and lack of clarification.

Comment: Confusing setup you have there. Can you explain why you have done it this way and what you are actually trying to achieve? 

Why do you need to go from MainViewController to TargetTableViewController instead of HoldingViewController? TargetTableViewController is a child of HoldingViewController so that is most likely why you are getting issues when you try and jump straight to it.

Comment: Apologies. I actually do want to target HoldingViewController, as that would in effect show the TargetTableViewController. I will amend my question accordingly.

Comment: Kia ora ... fellow Kiwi :-)

Comment: Nice to meet you ;) 

Setup a segue from MainViewController to NavViewControllerTwo in the storyboard, give it an identifier and then perform that segue from your code on button press action using [self performSegueWithIdentifier....

Comment: Likewise ;) ... I was really over-thinking this problem. Thank you for pointing out the path of least resistance. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Do you mind if I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a segue from MainViewController to NavViewControllerTwo in the storyboard, give it an identifier and then perform that segue from your code on the button press action using [self performSegueWithIdentifier...